# How to use java.util.Optional with REST API?

Tags: java, json, java-8, jackson

I have a class that looks like

```
public class ActiveDirectorySetup implements Serializable {
  private ActiveDirectoryDataSource activeDirectoryDataSource;
  private Optional<ShActiveDirectorySettings> shActiveDirectorySettings;
  private Optional<SaActiveDirectorySettings> saActiveDirectorySettings;
 // ...
}
```

I send this over the API as

```
      Optional<ActiveDirectoryConfiguration> configuration = store.getConfiguration();
      if (configuration.isPresent()) {
        return configuration.get();
      }
```

What I see on the browser is

```
[
   {
      "activeDirectoryDataSource":{
         "host":"localhost",
         "port":0,
         "userName":"user",
         "password":"password",
         "activeDirectoryQueryConfig":{
            "base":{
               "present":false
            },
            "filter":"filter",
            "attributes":[

            ]
         },
         "activeDirectorySslSettings":{
            "present":false
         }
      },
      "shActiveDirectorySettings":{
         "present":true
      },
      "saActiveDirectorySettings":{
         "present":true
      }
   }
]
```

for a payload that looks like

```
{
    "activeDirectorySetups": [
        {
            "activeDirectoryDataSource": {
                "host": "localhost",
                "port": 0,
                "userName": "user",
                "password": "password",
                "activeDirectoryQueryConfig": {
                    "base": null,
                    "filter": "filter",
                    "attributes": []
                },
                "activeDirectorySslSettings": null
            },
            "shActiveDirectorySettings": {
                "enableUserMapping": true,
                "attributes": null
            },
            "saActiveDirectorySettings": null
        }
    ]
}
```

As you could see, I get `{"present":true}` instead of the actual value.

I am using [jackson-datatype-jdk8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jdk8) for this work. How can I force it to replace `{"present":true}` with actual values - either `null` or 
`{"enableUserMapping": true, "attributes": null}`

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you'd need to write custom serialization / deserialization functionality for this.

#### Deserializer

```java
public class OptionalDeserializer<T> extends StdDeserializer<Optional<T>> {

    private ObjectMapper customObjectMapper;

    private Class<T> type;

    /**
     * @param customObjectMapper any ObjectMapper, possibly with deserialization logic for the wrapped type
     * @param type the wrapped type
     */
    public OptionalDeserializer(ObjectMapper customObjectMapper, Class<T> type) {
        this(Optional.class);
        this.customObjectMapper = customObjectMapper;
        this.type = type;
    }

    // At least one type-based constructor is required by Jackson
    private OptionalDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<T> deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext ctx) throws IOException {
        // Read entire tree
        JsonNode treeNode = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);

        // Check if "present" is true
        if (treeNode.has("present") && treeNode.get("present").asBoolean()) {
            // Read your wrapped value
            return Optional.of(customObjectMapper.treeToValue(treeNode.get("data"), type));
        }

        // Return empty() by default
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

#### Serializer

Note you could include a custom `ObjectMapper` for the `Box` type anywhere in the pipeline. It's omitted in the serializer for simplicity.

```java
public class OptionalSerializer<T> extends StdSerializer<Optional<T>> {

    public OptionalSerializer(Class<T> type) {
        this(TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructParametricType(Optional.class, type));
    }

    protected OptionalSerializer(JavaType javaType) {
        super(javaType);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Optional<T> value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        if (value.isPresent()) {
            gen.writeBooleanField("present", true);
            gen.writeObjectField("data", value.get());
        } else {
            gen.writeBooleanField("present", false);
        }
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

#### Example usage:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper optionalMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    // Add any custom deserialization logic for Box objects to this mapper
    ObjectMapper boxMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    OptionalDeserializer<Box> boxOptionalDeserializer = new OptionalDeserializer<>(boxMapper, Box.class);
    OptionalSerializer<Box> boxOptionalSerializer = new OptionalSerializer<>(Box.class);
    module.addDeserializer(Optional.class, boxOptionalDeserializer);
    // use addSerializer(JsonSerializer<?> ser), not addSerializer(Class<? extends T> type, JsonSerializer<T> ser)
    // The generic types involved here will otherwise not let the program compile
    module.addSerializer(boxOptionalSerializer);
    optionalMapper.registerModule(module);

    String json = "{\"present\": true, \"data\": {\"myValue\": 123}}";
    Optional optional = optionalMapper.readValue(json, Optional.class);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // Guaranteed safe cast
    Optional<Box> boxOptional = (Optional<Box>) optional;

    // Prints "123"
    boxOptional.ifPresent(box -> System.out.println(box.getMyValue()));

    // Prints the contents of "json" (variable defined above)
    System.out.println(optionalMapper.writeValueAsString(boxOptional));
}
```

Where `Box` is just a simple example class:

```java
private static class Box {
    private int myValue;

    public int getMyValue() {
        return myValue;
    }

    public void setMyValue(int myValue) {
        this.myValue = myValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you are relying on default java serialization while using Optional in Java 8. 
Kindly note that Optional is not serializable and hence, you will have to write your own JSON serializer/deserializer.

Comment: Serializable marker interface is most often not needed for 3rd party serializers like jackson