# Jackson deserializes absent optionals as nulls instead of Optional.empty()

Tags: java, jackson, option-type, optional-parameters, jackson-databind

Recently I've stumbled upon this problem:

Let's have an example java class that contains Optional property:

```java
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private static class DeserializingTestBean {
        private String stringProperty;
        private Optional<String> optionalStringProperty;
    }
```

I've noticed that deserializing a json string to this object produces two different results depending on the json string:

CASE #1

```json
{
 "stringProperty": "test",
 "optionalStringProperty": null
}
```

Using the Json String above we would get DeserializingTestBean object that will have `stringProperty` set as `test` and the `optionalStringProperty` set as `Optional.empty()` which is normal in this case. But let's check case 2.

CASE #2

```json
{
 "stringProperty": "test"
}
```

As you can notice the optional parameter is absent from this json string. When it creates the DeserializingTestBean object the optional parameter is set to `null` which means we can get potential NPE if we call the `.isPresent()` method.

There is a solution to this problem - we need to instantiate the `Optional<String>` parameter to `Optional.empty()`.

Is there an easier solution for a project where we have hundreds of such parameters that are not instantiated to `Optional.empty()` ?

I've considered the `objectMapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module().configureAbsentsAsNulls(true));` but it is not working. The method seems deprecated as well. Is there another configuration that I can use instead of instantiating every single Optional?

Comment: Can you change your constructor to check for null and replace it with empty optional?

Comment: It is possible but it is the same as instantiating the optional variable. I'd have to go through every occurrence of not initialized optionals.

Comment: If this is how Jackson is supposed to be working, I don't think you can do anything.

Comment: Found this, I think this solves your problem exactly, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38777128/how-to-use-java-util-optional-with-rest-api